# Storing multiple dates for each row of a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I am making a site for booking trucks online. I am using MySql for database. I have a Table called "Available_Bookings", each row of which  stores a truck, its driver name , driver contact number etc. The truck has some fixed dates on which it can operate. These dates can be 1,2 or any in number. Given a truck I need to know the dates on which it operates.

Any suggestions.. how to design my db?

Thanks

Comment: What you are asking about is [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). The Wikipedia article may help you to understand the topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a table which has two columns, one for storing the truck_id and date_operational. For each date that a particular truck is operational, insert one entry into this table.

Eg.

```
truck_id  |  date_operational  
----------------------------  
     1    |  12-07-2012  
     1    |  17-07-2012  
     2    |  13-07-2012
     3    |  12-07-2012  
     3    |  17-07-2012
```

Update -

```
Given a truck I need to know the dates on which it operates.
```

For this you may use the simple query -

```
SELECT date_operational FROM <tablename> WHERE truck_id = <desired_truck>;
```

Comment: …and you can set both columns to a single `PRIMARY` OR `UNIQUE` key, to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's whats i was thinking initially but i thought may be a better answer exists. What do u recommend to use for selecting multiple dates in front end?

Comment: This might be useful - http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html . It allows you to pick multiple dates as well. Jquery-ui date-picker would allow selecting only a single date.

Answer (score 0):

Separate truck and driver info into another table, with primary key being truck/driver ID, then store multiple rows with with ID in Available_Bookings , each time with another date.

If same truck can have multiple drivers - separate that as well, and use truck_id,driver_id pairs in Available_Bookings

Then you can query Available_Bookings by truck_id and get a list of available dates